# Presto: Filtering by Row Number

Tags: sql, filter, presto, row-number, trino

Can anyone help me to translate Teradata SQL `QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER` into Presto:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id DESC) > 5000000 
AND ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id DESC) <= 10000000;
```

Or provide some suggestions how to extract large datasets by row filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand there is no direct analog for `QUALIFY` clause in PrestoSQL/Trino. You can just use `ROW_NUMBER` [window function](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html)  in subquery (or CTE) and then filter based on that. Something like the following:

```sql
SELECT col_list_except_rn
FROM (SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id DESC) rn
    FROM table1)
WHERE rn BETWEEN 5000001 AND 10000000;
```

Comment: In my experience with Presto/Trino, you cannot use window functions in a WHERE clause.

Comment: @ChoNuff Balid point. Though it can easily be "fixed" with subquery. Will update the answer with valid query when get to computer.

Comment: Agreed. Also, I had posted another comment, then deleted it, as it had no relevance to the original question.

Comment: @ChoNuff updated to the example to a valid PrestoSQL query, thank you again!